# Rails- Loading user's page 'Couldn't find User with id=id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I am trying to do is to go to user's page after signin/up. On the error page is written that the error is in users_controller. So this is my user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find([:id])
  end

  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your show method should be:

```
def show
  @user = User.find( params[:id] )
end
```

And not `[:id]` alone. You're accessing the `:id` key at the `params` hash object.